# Replacing inline SVG with USE / external svg file tag prevents a hyperlink from actioning

Tags: html, svg, hyperlink, anchor

I am using svg to draw a picture then then make that a hyperlink with an anchor tag which when clicked will jump to a new url. This works on IE when I put the svg path inline but when I replace that with a "use" tag the target hyperlink no longer works. When the mouse hovers over the svg drawn picture the target hyperlink is shown at the bottom of the browser in both cases but with "use" clicking it doesn't work. I have tried with a g tag wrapped around the anchor tag but that didn't help.

Appreciate any feedback, thanks. Note: my actual requirement isn't this trivial but I have reduced the problem to this to help pinpoint the issue. I really want to take the svg out into a .svg file so I can re-use it without needing to duplicate it in multiple .html files.

So this is good in .html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  id="svgMap">
<a id="region1" xlink:href="target2.html">
<path d="
  M 0,0 L 0,100 L 100,100 Z"/>
</a>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I take out the path into an .svg file and then linking it in a  prevents the hyperlink from being followed. In both cases the svg is drawn correctly.

This doesnt work:-
.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      id="svgMap">
    <a id="region1" xlink:href="target2.html">
    <use xlink:href="example1.svg#target"></use>
</a>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

example1.svg

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   id="target"
   >
       <path d="
  M 0,0 L 0,100 L 100,100 Z"/>

</svg>
```

I have also tried replacing

```
<a id="region1" xlink:href="target2.html">
```

with

```
<a id="region1" href="target2.html">
```

but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the anchor tag around the svg and use tags solved the problem, like this:-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="target2.html">
  <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      id="svgMap">
  <use xlink:href="example1.svg#target"></use>
  </svg>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```